# When doing trigonometric substitution what is the advantage of using $\tan^2(\theta)+1=\sec^2(\theta)$ over $\cot^2(\theta)+1=\csc^2(\theta)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I remember my professor said something related to the domain and how using $\tan^2(\theta)+1=\sec^2(\theta)$ over $\cot^2(\theta)+1=\csc^2(\theta)$ will make it so that we can get rid of the absolute value of our final result. Can someone elaborate why is this?

Comment: It relates to them. We use trigonometric substitution to get rid of the rads when we have something such as $\int_{}^{} x^2/(\sqrt{9-x^2})$

Comment: Since $\cot^2\theta=\tan^2(\pi/2+\theta)$ and $\csc^2\theta=\sec^2(\pi/2+\theta)$, I'd say that using one or the other is exactly the same.

Comment: In the context above (the integral) would it be considered the same? I know you need to account for the domain in one and not on the other because universal assumptions, I just can't remember what it was.

Comment: Is substitution not $x = 3sin\theta$?

Comment: It doesn't actually matter, but the tan/sec way has fewer minus signs in intermediate calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with an indefinite integral with a radical ($y^2 = x$ implies $y = | \sqrt {x}|$ because $y = \pm \sqrt {x}$) and know that the integral you're working with is positive, absolute value bars are not required.  If you're working with limits on the integral, then you would have to keep the absolute value bars to determine the limits on the new integral.

Example: For $\int \sqrt {x^2 + 25} \ \ dx$, when we make the substitution $x = \tan \theta$, when squaring $x$ to get rid of the radical, $\tan^2 \theta$ will be positive, so the absolute value bars are not necessary.  On the other hand $\int_{-5}^{5} \sqrt {x^2 + 25} \ \ dx$, we have to be careful of the limits, so the absolute value is required.  (However, once we find the correct integral, we can substitute the values right in.)

I don't think I've seen a subsitution using $x = \cot \theta$ - mainly the ones used are $x = \sin \theta$, $x = \sec \theta$, and $x = \tan \theta$.  EDIT: In certain circumstances, $x = \cot \theta$ can be used, but very rarely.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. I have been having trouble understanding absolute values in the context of integrals as well. I heard that it is possible to use any of the pythagorean identities but for some such as the cotθ we can't get rid of the absolute values unless we specify the domain?

Comment: If you're working with definite integrals with limits, yes, the domain must be determined first before removing the absolute value sign; indefinite integrals can be assumed to be positive and thus absolute value signs are not required.